# wired java func always return null

Tags: java

```
protected String doInBackground(View... params) {
    mView = params[0];
    Account[] accounts = com.xxx.xxx.app.AccountManager
            .get(mView.getContext()).getAccounts();
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        return HttpUtils.getVPNConf(accounts[0].name);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "get vpnconf failed");
    }
    return null;
}
```

in Android 4.2 emulator
here is a code snippet, `accounts.length == 1` but either DEBUG or nonDEBUG the func always return null
i am a java newbie, can someone explain it for me?

Comment: Have you tried determining the contents of `accounts` after instantiation? Could be as simple as `com.xxx.xxx.app.AccountManager.get(mView.getContext()).getAccounts()`
always returning an empty array.

Comment: If `accounts.length` is greater than *zero*, then `HttpUtils.getVPNConf(accounts[0].name)` seems to be returning `null`. There is no other explanation other than this. You need to debug your code and check the values at every step.

Comment: @R.J when debug by step, it first run to `return HttpUtils.getVPNConf(accounts[0].name);` then `return null;`

Answer (score 0):

There possibly three point(maybe more) that may cause return,

1. check your accounts[0].name
2. check the function of HttpUtils.getVPNConf
3. double check the length of the Account[]

also, have you added the permission for getting account information in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

checking carefully should be able to solve your problem.